# How to do I properly send variables using pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I currently am having trouble using pagination. The first page is great, and the display on the second and third pages are correct, but the actual $_Get variables are not being carried over  onto the second page and third page. Where would I put the actual $_Get Variables to go onto the next pages? Also I am using a form to pass the variables as a hidden input, that again work on the first page, but revert to empty on the second and third pages. I have read about decoupling and using sessions, but have tried implementing session variables at the top to no avail. How would I get the session to go to the second and third page. Thank you!

```
session_start();
include "dbhReal.inc.php";
include "header.php";
 $timeSelected = $_GET['time'];
 $dateSelected = $_GET['date'];
 $ShownDate = date('M-d-y', strtotime("$dateSelected"));
$Null = '00:00:00';
<!--Form is below, left out the queries for space sake-->
 echo '
       <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card h-100">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="../PhotoUploads/uploads/'.$userPic['Link1'].'" height="350" width="400" alt="anotherOne"/>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">'.$row['firstNameP'].' '.$row['lastNameP'].'</h5>
        <p class="card-text">'.$row['briefDescription'].'</p>
       <form action="settingTheSession.php" method="GET">   
                   <input type="hidden" name="time" value='.$timeSelected.'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="date" value='.$dateSelected.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idNumber" value='.$boookingNumber.'>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buttonBookprofileSearch">See Profile</button>
                    </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
<!--Pagnation-->
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item" <?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo "class='page-item disabled'"; } ?>>
    <a class='page-link' <?php if($page_no > 1){ echo "href='?page_no=$previous_page'"; } ?>>Previous</a>
    </li>
    <?php 
    if ($total_no_of_pages <= 10){       
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $total_no_of_pages; $counter++){
            if ($counter == $page_no) {
           echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link'>$counter</a></li>";  
                }else{
           echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                }
        }
    }
    elseif($total_no_of_pages > 10){

    if($page_no <= 4) {         
     for ($counter = 1; $counter < 8; $counter++){       
            if ($counter == $page_no) {
           echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link'>$counter</a></li>";  
                }else{
           echo "<li class='page-item' ><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                }
        }
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a>...</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$second_last'>$second_last</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>$total_no_of_pages</a></li>";
        }

     elseif($page_no > 4 && $page_no < $total_no_of_pages - 4) {         
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=1'>1</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=2'>2</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link'>...</a></li>";
        for ($counter = $page_no - $adjacents; $counter <= $page_no + $adjacents; $counter++) {         
           if ($counter == $page_no) {
           echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link'counter</a></li>";    
                }else{
           echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                }                  
       }
       echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link'>...</a></li>";
       echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$second_last'>$second_last</a></li>";
       echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>$total_no_of_pages</a></li>";      
            }

        else {
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=1'>1</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=2'>2</a></li>";
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link'>...</a></li>";

        for ($counter = $total_no_of_pages - 6; $counter <= $total_no_of_pages; $counter++) {
          if ($counter == $page_no) {
           echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link'>$counter</a></li>";  
                }else{
           echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
                }                   
                }
            }
    }
?>
    <li class="page-item" <?php if($page_no >= $total_no_of_pages){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
    <a class="page-link" <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages) { echo "href='?page_no=$next_page'"; } ?>>Next</a>
    </li>
    <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages){
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a></li>";
        } ?>


</ul>


           <div class="text-center">
               <strong>Page <?php echo $page_no." of ".$total_no_of_pages; ?></strong></div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first try not to reinvent the wheel. There are a lot of packages out there which deal with pagination: https://packagist.org/packages/voku/pagination?query=pagination

---

Secondly, considering your question, as PHP is server side you need to pass the needed data to every page/url you navigate.

So like the following example from your code:

```
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=1'>1</a></li>";
```

You will need the add the wanted arguments to the href query string. Like you are already doing with the 'page_no' parameter.

```
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='?page_no=1&date=". $dateSelected ."'>1</a></li>";
```

In that manner you will have access to the wanted arguments on the next pages.

Comment: You are awesome! That was exactly what I needed and thank you for that resource. I kept getting very snotty and rude comments on this. This was immensely helpful.